# Cannot insert the value NULL into column with procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is not a duplicate.

I do understand what the issue means but I don't understand why because the variable contains data. I'm basically trying to make a char(4) column increase alone (just like identity with integers). If the table doesn't contain anything, the first value would be 'C001' otherwise, It simply increase based on the last record.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_CL(@nom VARCHAR(20),
                        @dn  DATE)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @B CHAR(4)
      DECLARE @B_to_int INT
      DECLARE @B_new_value CHAR(4)

      IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM   CLIENT)
        SET @B_new_value = 'C001'
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 @B = code_client
            FROM   client
            ORDER  BY code_client DESC

            SET @B_to_int = CAST(SUBSTRING(@B, 2, 3) AS INTEGER)
            SET @B_to_int = @B_to_int + 1;
            SET @B_new_value = LEFT(@B, 1) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@B_to_int AS INT), 3)
        END

      INSERT INTO CLIENT
      VALUES     (@B_new_value,
                  @nom,
                  @dn)
  END
```

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'code_client', table 'dbo.CLIENT'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

@B_new_value represent code_client

Comment: This kind of roll your own identitish type of numbering has way too many challenges. For starters getting the "next" value is a bit a pain as you have discovered. And getting the right value is a bit of a challenge too because it is character data you are sorting. Last but not least is the very real challenge that you have with concurrency and race conditions. If you have multiple people trying to call your procedure you may actually get duplicate values. Using an identity solves all these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your `If Exists` should be `If Not Exists`.

So change

```
if exists(select TOP 1 * from CLIENT)
```

to

```
if not exists(select TOP 1 * from CLIENT)
```

Also you are adding `00` to your final `@B_to_int` which is cast as `int`. so it will show `C2,C3` and so on.

If you want to retain the same format, cast it to varchar

<s>SET @B_new_value = LEFT(@B,1) + '00' + CAST(@B_to_int as varchar)</s>

Above line will work only till the count is 9. and then it will continue replicating itself with 1 because 10 will be `0010` and final output will be `C0010`. To eliminate this issue, use replicate and replicate `0` until 3 characters.

```
SET @B_new_value = LEFT(@B,1) + REPLICATE('0',3-LEN(@B_to_int)) + @B_to_int
```

Good Luck.

Comment: That worked indeed however, when I tried 'char' instead of varchar. It gave me the 'C' letter only, why is that?

Comment: I only had to change the result to varchar. the code I made above worked just fine. I made a loop to insert 900 times and worked fine with 'RIGHT' instead of replicate.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already tell you that you should be using `NOT EXISTS`.

This numbering scheme is quite possibly something you'll regret but you could simplify this a lot as well as making it safer in conditions of concurrency and when you run out of numbers by just doing

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_CL(@nom VARCHAR(20),
                        @dn  DATE)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @B VARCHAR(5);

      SET XACT_ABORT ON;

      BEGIN TRAN

      SELECT @B = FORMAT(1 + RIGHT(ISNULL(MAX(code_client), 'C000'), 3), '\C000')
      FROM   CLIENT WITH(ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK);

      IF ( LEN(@B) > 4 )
        THROW 50000, 'Exceeded range',1;

      INSERT INTO CLIENT
      VALUES      (@B,
                   @nom,
                   @dn);

      COMMIT
  END
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. If you take a look at AVG answer, you will see that he proposed varchar instead of char. If I use char in his case, I will only get "C" letter, is there is any reason behind that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should be 'NOT EXISTS'

```
if EXISTS(select TOP 1 * from CLIENT)
```

Comment: See @AVK's answer for the answer to that one!